# svn Difference betwenn BASE & COMMITTED

Tags: svn

please tell me in which situation BASE and COMMITTED revisions can have differences?

We can read [in docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html):

> COMMITTED -- The most recent revision prior to, or equal to, BASE, in which an item changed.

But I can't understand why we need special name COMMITTED (what is that *moment* when it isn't like BASE?)

Comment: A file in a given revision may not have been edited for along while.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález or even a short while; basically a file which wasn't changed as part of the last commit has a different COMMITTED revision to BASE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BASE revision is the last revision your working copy was checked out or updated to where as COMMITTED is the last change to a file or folder.

If you check out a repository at revision 10 you'll have the BASE of 10.  if a file in that repository was last changed at revision 8, it will still have a BASE of 10, but the COMMITTED will be 8, as that's when it was last changed.